# Possible way to Filter Multiple grid Value Kendo Grid

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, kendo-ui

I'm stuck in this situation that i need to Filter Duplicate data entry in my Kendo Grid when Saving Drop Down Value.

I have this Dropdown that shows day of the Week e.g Monday, Tuesday and so on

But i want to prevent this by showing a message that will prevent the user to save the day that is saved before unless delete it. Can someone Help me with this situation??

My Drop down List :

```
    <span>
 @Html.DropDownList("dllFromDay", new SelectList(ViewBag.DayList, "ID", "Display_Value", tFromDay), "[Please Select]")
            </span>
```

Controller for Viewbag:

```
 private void GetDayList()
{

    var daylist = (from a in db.Lookups
                     where a.Domain == "AVAILABLEDAY"
                     select a).ToList();
    ViewBag.DayList= daylist ;
}
```

Thanks :)